# How to only keep data surrounding a line/column intersection in Pandas Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have an array with column indices for each row like this:

```
 array = [NaN, 3, 4, 3, NaN]
```

And a pandas data frame like this:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6
 1   1  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1
 2   1   1   1  NaN NaN  1
 3  NaN  1   1   1   1   1 
 4  NaN  1   1   1  NaN  1
 5   1  NaN  1  NaN NaN  1
```

Basically, I want to only keep data that **intersects and is surrounded by my column index.**

How do I keep values that overlap with my column index for each row such that I get a data frame like this:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6
 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2    1   1   1  NaN NaN NaN
 3   NaN  1   1   1   1   1 
 4   NaN  1   1   1  NaN NaN
 5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Where data associated with my rows column index is preserved?

---

Comparing the input and output, you can see the cells that are marked by the `array` are shown as tick marks.

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6
 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1
 2    1   1   ✓  NaN NaN  1
 3   NaN  1   1   ✓   1   1 
 4   NaN  1   ✓   1  NaN  1
 5    1 NaN   1 NaN  NaN  1
```

From here, all the surrounding non-null cells (in the same row) must also be kept:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6
 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1
 2    ✓   ✓   ✓  NaN NaN  1
 3   NaN  ✓   ✓   ✓   ✓   ✓ 
 4   NaN  ✓   ✓   ✓  NaN  1
 5    1 NaN   1 NaN  NaN  1
```

Making the result:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6
 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2    1   1   1  NaN NaN NaN
 3   NaN  1   1   1   1   1 
 4   NaN  1   1   1  NaN NaN
 5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Why is column `6` masked in the 2nd and 4th row?

Comment: Please make your question more clear .

Comment: @Martijn I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @coldspeed: that's quite a leap of deduction. It happens to fit the given expected output, lets hope it is what the OP actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

> I see that my `6` column is different from the one you provided in your test case, but as its masking in the test case does not follow the pattern of the other columns, I think that is what you meant.

Hope this helps:

```
index = [np.nan, 3, 4, 3, np.nan]
to_nan_mask = [x is np.nan for x in index]
df.loc[to_nan_mask, df.columns] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
2   NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
3   NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN 1.0
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: What I don't understand is the roll of the actual column numbers `3, 4, 3` in the index.

Comment: I did not understand its meaning as well, I considered it to be a boolean column and built it that way.